# Is there any available Processing program profiler?

Tags: profiler, processing

My project is coded in [Processing](http://processingjs.org/), is there available profiler for Processing? If not, how to test the performance of Processing program?

Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: Please specify what kind of profiling/performance you are interested in.
Basically, processing is a Java and JVM based language, and can be profiled with all kind of Java default profiling tools, like JVisualVM, GC log profiling, etcetera.
Other profiling can include simple timing loops around or inside the draw function. Also, how is your Procession project setup ? Is it run from inside the Processing environment, or do you call it from a Java project/IDE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to profile my Processing applications. Simply navigate to the appropriate process in VisualVM while your sketch is running. Processing is fundamentally Java, so most Java tools will work on your Processing apps.

EDIT: Processing.js sketches can also be profiled by using the Developer Tools extensions in browsers, just run a CPU profile.